# How do I get all UI elements of a Web Dynpro Java view?

Tags: java, user-interface, netweaver, webdynpro

Is there any way to recursively iterate over all elements inside the root element of a Web Dynpro Java view?

For each found child element I would like to read/modify properties at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate child elements of root element you should access root in `wdDoModifyView()` method:

```
IWDUIElementContainer root = (IWDUIElementContainer) view.getRootElement();
IWDUIElement[] elements = root.getChildren();
 for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      IWDUIElement element = elements[i];
      String id = element.getId();

      if (id.equals("Button")) {
          IWDButton button = (IWDButton)view.getElement(id);
          button.setText("someText");
      }

 }
```